# What is the Python way of chaining maps and filters?

Tags: python

I'm currently learning Python (coming from other languages like JavaScript and Ruby). I am very used to chaining a bunch of transformations / filters, but I'm pretty sure that's not the right way to do it in Python: `filter` takes a lambda before the enumerable, so writing a long / multi-line function looks really weird and chaining them means putting them in reverse order which isn't readable.

What would be the "Python way" of writing the maps and filters in this JavaScript function?

```
let is_in_stock = function() /* ... */
let as_item = function() /* ... */

let low_weight_items = shop.inventory
    .map(as_item)
    .filter(is_in_stock)
    .filter(item => item.weight < 1000)
    .map(item => {
        if (item.type == "cake") {
            let catalog_item = retrieve_catalog_item(item.id);

            return {
                id: item.id,
                weight: item.weight,
                barcode: catalog_item.barcode
            };
        } else {
            return default_transformer(item);
        }
    });
```

I understand that I might use a list comprehension for the first map and the next two filters, but I am not sure how to do the last map and how to put everything together.

Thank you!

Comment: You *could* write a named function for that last map and use list comprehensions for the others.  While I personally prefer map/filter/reduce most pythonistas seem to prefer list comprehensions.  You should try to do this a piece (or two) at a time with list comprehensions just to get used to them either way.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One good way to do this is to combine multiple filters/maps into a single generator comprehension.  In cases where this can't be done, define an intermediate variable for the intermediate map/filter you need, instead of trying to force the maps into a single chain.  For instance:

```
def is_in_stock(x):
   # ...
def as_item(x):
   # ...
def transform(item):
    if item.type == "cake":
        catalog_item = retrieve_catalog_item(item.id)
        return {
            "id": item.id,
            "weight": item.weight,
            "barcode": catalog_item.barcode
        }
    else:
        return default_transformer(item)

items = (as_item(item) for item in shop.inventory)
low_weight_items = (transform(item) for item in items if is_in_stock(item) and item.weight < 1000)
```

Note that the actual application of the maps and filters is all done in the last two lines.  The earlier part is just defining the functions that encode the maps and filters.

The second generator comprehension does the last two filters and the map all together.  Using generator comprehensions means that each original item in `inventory` will be mapped/filtered lazily.  It won't pre-process the entire list, so it is likely to perform better if the list is large.

Note that there is no Python equivalent to defining long functions inline as in your JavaScript example.  You can't specify that complex filter (the one with `item.type == "cake"`) inline.  Instead, as shown in my example, you *must* define it as a separate function, just as you did with `is_in_stock` and `as_item`.

(The reason the first map was split is that later filters can't act on the mapped data until after it's mapped.  It could be combined into one, but that would require manually redoing the `as_item` map inside the comprehension:

```
low_weight_items = (transform(as_item(item)) for item in items if is_in_stock(as_item(item)) and as_item(item).weight < 1000)
```

It's clearer to just separate out that map.)

Comment: +1 for style, which sounds readable and Pythonic. While other solutions do seem to be running, your code looks natural and readable in Python.

Comment: I will second that this is nice looking code ... (+1)

Comment: Thanks so much! I was wondering what the best way to define that complex filter was. Super clear now!

Comment: @BrenBarn Are the Python `map` and `generator` equally efficient? Timing gave: `map(lambda x*x, range(100))` < `(x*x for x in range(100))`.

Answer (score 55):

If you don't mind using a package, this is another way to do it using https://github.com/EntilZha/PyFunctional

```
from functional import seq

def as_item(x):
    # Implementation here
    return x

def is_in_stock(x):
    # Implementation
    return True

def transform(item):
    if item.type == "cake":
        catalog_item = retrieve_catalog_item(item.id);
        return {
            'id': item.id,
            'weight': item.weight,
            'barcode': catalog_item.barcode
        }
    else:
        return default_transformer(item)

low_weight_items = seq(inventory)\
    .map(as_item)\
    .filter(is_in_stock)\
    .filter(lambda item: item.weight < 1000)\
    .map(transform)
```

As mentioned earlier, python lets you use lamdba expressions, but they aren't flexible as clojures in javascript since they can't have more than one statement. Another annoying python thing are the need for backslashes. That being said, I think the above most closely mirrors what you originally posted.

Disclaimer: I am the author of the above package

Comment: **Note:** The backslashes can be removed if you wrap the seq object and its chain of calls in parentheses. See the github readme for examples. --- _(I know you wrote this package, but I'm writing this for others to see)_

Comment: Finally something useful and readable! This is the way it should be done.

Answer (score 10):

use iterators (in python 3 all those functions are iterators in python2 you need to use itertools.imap and itertools.ifilter)

```
m = itertools.imap
f = itertools.ifilter
def final_map_fn(item):
   if (item.type == "cake"):
        catalog_item = retrieve_catalog_item(item.id);
        return {
            "id": item.id,
            "weight": item.weight,
            "barcode": catalog_item.barcode}
    else:
        return default_transformer(item)

items = m(as_item,shop.inventory) #note it does not loop it yet
instockitems = f(is_in_stock,items) #still hasnt actually looped anything
weighteditems = (item for item instockitems if item.weight < 100) #still no loop (this is a generator)
final_items = m(final_map_fn,weighteditems) #still has not looped over a single item in the list
results = list(final_items) #evaluated now with a single loop
```

Comment: +1 for very well explained beauty of iterators (and all the flavours and relatives of them). Yes - Python is able to be like a tube, being able to make complex transformation for long iterables.

Comment: This works, but I think list/generator comprehensions are usually more readable than map/filter applications, especially when the map-filters require lambda-izing expressions that could be written inline in a comprehension (as in your filter for `weightitems`).

Comment: @BrenBarn modified to use a generator for the lambda as you are correct it does look better (especially for that one)

Comment: Given that functional programming prioritizes the removal of assignment, I have to say that this solution lacks grace entirely in any sense of approaching the functional norm. I don't think this is at all in the spirit of FP. Which really has me wonder if Python is at all really appropriate for FP.

Answer (score 7):

Defining your own functional composition meta-function is pretty easy. Once you have that, chaining functions together is also very easy.

```
import functools
def compose(*functions):
    return functools.reduce(lambda f, g: lambda x: f(g(x)), functions)
def make_filter(filter_fn):
    return lambda iterable: (it for it in iterable if filter_fn(it))

pipeline = compose(as_item, make_filter(is_in_stock),
                   make_filter(lambda item: item.weight < 1000),
                   lambda item: ({'id': item.id,
                                 'weight': item.weight,
                                 'barcode': item.barcode} if item.type == "cake"
                                 else default_transformer(item)))
pipeline(shop.inventory)
```

If you're not already familiar with iterators, I would brush up on it if I were you (something like http://excess.org/article/2013/02/itergen1/ is good).

Comment: This is a solution, but I would definitely not call it a Pythonic solution.

Comment: Python is a functional language--since all the other solutions are procedural and not functional, IMO this is the most Pythonic solution on the page. None of the others take full advantage of Python's capacity for meta-programming.

Comment: It would also be a shame for the OP to have to lose a very good programming paradigm in his move to Python.

Comment: @metaperture Nope. Using all the features of Python does not mean, it is the most Pythonic. For calling something Pythonic, try reading Zen of Python (`$ python -c "import this"`)

Comment: I'm not claiming that you should always use all the features of python, I'm claiming that functional python is pythonic.

Comment: Python has functional programming capabilities, but bending over backwards to use them is not Pythonic.  Some tasks are elegantly solved in Python using functional technqiues; others are not.  It's not really a matter of functional vs. other paradigms; this approach is simply much less readable than an iterator-based solution for this task.

Comment: Comments to PEP 309 note functional composition is absent, with some listed opinions (comp.lang.python and python-dev) claiming that composition is pythonic and should be included by default in functools. I personally often come across problems where composing functionals happens in very separate places from applying said functionals to data, in which case iterators are simply not a possible solution.

Comment: make_filter can be simplified with functools.partial, as follow:
    def filterBy(filter_fn): return functools.partial(filter, filter_fn)

Similarly, one can partialize the builtin function map, to create a mapBy function.

Answer (score 2):

You can somewhat achieve this using the walrus operator in a generator comprehension.

```py
low_weight_items = (
    z
    for x in [
        Item(1, 100, "cake"),
        Item(2, 1000, "cake"),
        Item(3, 900, "cake"),
        Item(4, 10000, "cake"),
        Item(5, 100, "bread"),
    ]
    if (y := as_item(x))
    if is_in_stock(y)
    if y.weight < 1000
    if (z := transform(y))
)
```

But you have to assign different variables (`x/y/z` in the example) as you can't assign to an existing variable with the walrus operator.

---

#### Full example

```py
def as_item(x):
    return x

def is_in_stock(x):
    return True

class Item:
    def __init__(self, id, weight, type):
        self.id = id
        self.weight = weight
        self.type = type

class CatalogItem:
    def __init__(self, id, barcode):
        self.id = id
        self.barcode = barcode

def retrieve_catalog_item(id):
    return CatalogItem(id, "123456789")

def default_transformer(item):
    return item

def transform(item):
    if item.type == "cake":
        catalog_item = retrieve_catalog_item(item.id)
        return {
            'id': item.id,
            'weight': item.weight,
            'barcode': catalog_item.barcode,
        }
    else:
        return default_transformer(item)

low_weight_items = (
    z
    for x in [
        Item(1, 100, "cake"),
        Item(2, 1000, "cake"),
        Item(3, 900, "cake"),
        Item(4, 10000, "cake"),
        Item(5, 100, "bread"),
    ]
    if (y := as_item(x))
    if is_in_stock(y)
    if y.weight < 1000
    if (z := transform(y))
)

for item in low_weight_items:
    print(item)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use Pyterator: https://github.com/remykarem/pyterator (disclaimer: I'm the author). It's very similar to @EntilZha's library.

```sh
pip install git+https://github.com/remykarem/pyterator#egg=pyterator
```

Define functions

```py
def is_in_stock(x):
    pass

def as_item(x):
    pass

def transform_cake_noncake(item):
    pass
```

then

```py
from pyterator import iterate

low_weight_items = (
    iterate(shop.inventory)
    .map(as_item)
    .filter(is_in_stock)
    .filter(lambda item: item.weight < 1000)
    .map(transform_cake_noncake)
    .to_list()
)
```

Note that all the operations like `map` and `filter` are lazily evaluated. So you need to call `.to_list()` to evaluate the pipeline. Otherwise, it remains as an `Iterator` (which you can later use in a for-loop etc.).

Also similar to Fluentpy (https://github.com/dwt/fluent).

Answer (score 0):

```py
def is_in_stock():
    ...

def as_item():
    ...

def get_low_weight_items(items):
    for item in items:
        item = as_item(item)
        if not is_in_stock(item):
            continue
        if item.weight < 1000:
            if item.type == "cake":
                catalog_item = retrieve_catalog_item(item.id)
                yield {
                    "id": item.id,
                    "weight": item.weight,
                    "barcode": catalog_item.barcode,
                }
            else:
                yield default_transformer(item)


low_weight_items = list(get_low_weight_items(items))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from functools import reduce

class my_list(list):
    def filter(self, func):
        return my_list(filter(func, self))
    def map(self, func):
        return my_list(map(func, self))
    def reduce(self, func):
        return reduce(func, self)

temp = my_list([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
print(temp.filter(lambda n: n%2==0).map(lambda n: n*2).reduce(lambda a,b: a+b))
```

You can use inheritance to achieve the same thing in python, if you want to use inbuilt filter, map and reduce methods.
Here I have created a class called `my_list` which extends the `class list`. I will wrap my list with `my_list` and then use map, filter and reduce defined from my class by passing a function as a parameter.

I know that this will be creating a fresh object every time these three methods are invoked. If there is any way to bypass multiple object creation do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You could also create your own class like this.
You pass an iterable item to this stream class and create methods that delegates all needed operations to existing map, filter functions and the like.

```
class stream:
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        try:
            self.iterator = iter(iterable)
        except Exception:
            raise TypeError(f'{iterable} is not iterable but {type(iterable)}')

    def map(self, f):
        self.iterator = map(f, self.iterator)
        return self

    def filter(self, f):
        self.iterator = filter(f, self.iterator)
        return self

    def foreach(self, f):
        for x in self.iterator:
            f(x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    stream([1,2,3,4,5]).map(lambda x: x*2)\
                       .filter(lambda x:x>4)\
                       .foreach(lambda x: print(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to mention the [`streamable`](https://github.com/ebonnal/streamable) module I wrote (would love to get feedback!):

Your example would look like:

```py
from typing import Any, Dict, Iterable
from streamable import Stream

class Shop:
    inventory: Iterable[Any]

class Item:
    id: int
    weight: int
    type: str
    def __init__(self, inventory_item: Any): ...

class CatalogItem:
    barcode: str

def is_in_stock(item: Item) -> bool: ...
def retrieve_catalog_item(id: int) -> CatalogItem: ...
def default_transformer(item: Item) -> Dict[str, Any]: ...

shop: Shop = ...

low_weight_items: Stream[Dict[str, Any]] = (
    Stream(lambda: shop.inventory)
    .map(Item)
    .filter(is_in_stock)
    .filter(lambda item: item.weight < 1000)
    .map(lambda item:
        {
            "id": item.id,
            "weight": item.weight,
            "barcode": retrieve_catalog_item(item.id).barcode
        }
        if item.type == "cake" 
        else default_transformer(item),
        # use 2 threads in case retrieve_catalog_item involves expensive I/O
        concurrency=2,
    )
)
```

- this is a ***typed*** module with 100% code coverage and no dependency
- the `Stream[T]` class extends `Iterable[T]`
- a stream is ***immutable***
- operations are ***lazily evaluated*** and cover concurrency, grouping/flattening, exceptions catching, rate limiting, iteration progress logging, ...