# functional programming in python - using map(), filter(), and sum() together - java .stream() equivalent?

Tags: python, functional-programming

I'm learning about functional programming in Python and Java.

I've got some Java code that finds out the sum of double of even numbers from a list.

I'd like to use functional programming in Python to do the same thing (ie find the sum of double of even numbers from the list). What is good practice in terms of using filter(), map(), and sum() **together** and for the code to be **readable**?

What I've written in Python (see below) does the job but isn't very readable.

Thanks for any help!

```
# JAVA

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
public class GFG {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Integer> numbers
            = Arrays.asList(11, 22, 33, 44,
                            55, 66, 77, 88,
                            99, 100);
 
        System.out.println(
            numbers.stream()
                .filter(number -> number % 2 == 0)
                .mapToInt(e -> e * 2)
                .sum());
    }
}

// OUTPUT: 640
```

```
# PYTHON 

class GFG:

    @staticmethod
    def main():
        numbers = [11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99, 100]
        print(sum(map(lambda x: x * 2, (filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, numbers)))))
   

GFG.main()

# OUTPUT: 640
```

Comment: You could use `Stream.of` in java to make it more concise :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the Python way of chaining maps and filters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24831476/what-is-the-python-way-of-chaining-maps-and-filters)

Comment: the introduction of list comprehension replaced the need for  'filter()`, `map()` , and it is functional (immutable).

Comment: The good practice is not to use `map` and `filter` and just use comprehensions or generator expressions for mapping/filtering operations. There is no stream-like API in Python, which eschews fluent interfaces in the standard library. But I e never missed it, because I don't mind just assigning to an intermediate variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the Python is less readable is that `map`, `filter` etc are methods in Java while they are functions in Python. This means that in Java, you can use indentation to make everything read left-to-right in a fluid style.

There is no particularly reason you can't create your own stream in Python:

```
class MyStream:
     def __init__(iterator):
          self.iterator = iterator

     def map(func):
          return MyStream(map(func, self.iterator))
     
     def filter(func):
          return MyStream(filter(func, self.iterator))
     ...
```

No one would actually do this in Python because list comprehension and generator expressions are considered much more readable.

Comment: As you said, with Java Stream, everything is read from left to right in a fluid style. With Python's list comprehension, simple things are very easy to read, but if we need to map multiple levels, things are not that easy (or we will be flooded with so many temporary variables).

Answer (score 1):

Use `sum` with a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions).

```py
sum(x * 2 for x in numbers if x % 2 == 0)
```

Comment: I'd argue that this is still less readable than the java version. This answer look 'more like the chained version': https://stackoverflow.com/a/37632842/461499

Comment: @RobAudenaerde almost without doubt this is the preferred python approach. At first I wasn't sure whether it fully classed as functional programming but apparently the comprehension is borrowed from Haskell. So, two birds with one stone

Comment: I guess this is the 'pytonic' way for this small stream. But that is a bit my point I guess, if you want to add more filters and maps it becomes less en less readable, as opposed to a sequence / stream object that exposes these functional methods.

Comment: Being a method doesn't make it any more "functional" than using.. functions.

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley Are you referring to something in my answer?

Comment: No, I just forgot to @ the other commenter.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to mention the [`streamable`](https://github.com/ebonnal/streamable) module I wrote (would love to get feedback!):

Your example would look like:

```py
from typing import List
from streamable import Stream

numbers: List[int] = [11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99, 100]

print(
    sum(
        Stream(lambda: numbers)
        .filter(lambda number: number % 2 == 0)
        .map(lambda e: e * 2)
    )
)
```

```
640
```

- this is a ***typed*** module with 100% code coverage and no dependency
- the `Stream[T]` class extends `Iterable[T]`
- a stream is ***immutable***
- operations are ***lazily evaluated*** and cover concurrency, grouping/flattening, exceptions catching, rate limiting, iteration progress logging, ...